# trying to display an alert message with a variable with in the message

Tags: javascript, php, alert

alert message to display that a fieldname has not been entered. whenever i try to run the code an alert box gets displayed with no message but when I run the code without - ".$fieldname." the message is displayed . 
I want the fieldname that has not been entered to be displayed along with the message .

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
              $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
              $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
              $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
              $course = $_POST['course'];
              $semester = $_POST['semester'];
              $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
              $gender = $_POST['sex'];
             $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
              $password = $_POST['password'];
              $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];

              $fields = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'mobile', 'course', 'semester', 'DOB', 'sex', 'password', 'email_id');

               $error = false; //No errors yet
              foreach($fields AS $fieldname) 
                { //Loop trough each field
                  if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname]))
                    {
                       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('field'.$fieldname.'not entered');</script>";
                       //Display error with field

                      $error = true; //Yup there are errors
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: `alert('field".$fieldname."not entered')`

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('field'+ $fieldname +'not entered');</script>";
```

`+` work as concatenating operator with strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not using the correct delimiting quotes for the concatenation

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('field'.$fieldname.'not entered');</script>";
```

Will end up looking like (assume $fieldname contains the text *Something*)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('field'.Something.'not entered');</script>
```

when rendered to the page. Since *Something* is not quoted javascript will try to resolve it like a variable, and more than likely not find it and error out.

It should look like

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('field".$fieldname."not entered');</script>";
```

Note the double quote ending the first part and starting the next. Though you don't even need to do the concatenation, you can just put the variable name in the string. Php parses variables when inside double quotes

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('field $fieldname not entered');</script>";
```